# How to extract a string between square brackets

Tags: regex, powershell, groovy

I have to extract a string from square brackets using Powershell or Groovy script.

PowerShell :

```
$string = "[test][OB-110] this is some text"  

$found = $string -match '(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])'  
echo $matches
```

When I run the above code it returns :

```
test
```

I want it to return this :

```
test
OB-110
```

I need to extract all text within brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-match` will internally call `Regex.Match()` in the background, which in turn will only capture the first match.

Either use `Select-String` with the `-AllMatches` switch:

```
($string |Select-String '(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])' -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

Or invoke `Regex.Matches()` directly:

```
[regex]::Matches($string, '(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])').Value
```

Answer (score 3):

For Groovy:

```
def str = "[test][OB-110] this is some text"

str.findAll(/(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])/).each {
    println it
}
```

Which prints

```
test
OB-110
```